# Multiple nested routers in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is it possible to have multiple nested routers in an Express server?

Say I have a vehicle servicing business and I want to have my api split out into the different services and then split other actions etc:

```
app.use('/clean', cleanRoutes);
app.use('/repair', repairRoutes);
...
```

In the respective route files I have something like

```
const repairRoute = express.Router();

carRoute.get('/', (req, res) => { // does something });
carRoute.get('/wheels', (req, res) => { // does something });
carRoute.get('/wheels/tyres ...
...
```

Given this list of routes will likely become a large one, is it possible to move out the subpaths into another file, like another nested routes file?

Ie. something like

```
const repairRoute = express.Router();

carRoute.get('/', (req, res) => { // does something });
carRoute.get('/wheels', wheelRoutes);
```

with the wheelRoutes file being something like

```
carRoute.get('/wheels/tyres ...
```

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely possible to have nested routers in an Express server, and you can split your routes into multiple files for better organization. In your example, you can create a separate wheelRoutes file to handle routes related to wheels. Try something like this,

```js
// wheelRoutes.js
const express = require('express');
const wheelRoutes = express.Router();

wheelRoutes.get('/tyres', (req, res) => {
  // Handle /wheels/tyres route logic
});

// Add more routes related to wheels if needed

module.exports = wheelRoutes;
```

```js
// repairRoutes.js
const express = require('express');
const repairRoutes = express.Router();
const wheelRoutes = require('./wheelRoutes'); // Adjust the path accordingly

repairRoutes.get('/', (req, res) => {
  // Handle /repair route logic
});

// Use the wheelRoutes for /repair/wheels path
repairRoutes.use('/wheels', wheelRoutes);

// Add more routes related to repair if needed

module.exports = repairRoutes;
```

```js
// app.js
const express = require('express');
const cleanRoutes = require('./cleanRoutes'); // adjust path accordingly
const repairRoutes = require('./repairRoutes'); // adjust path accordingly
```